# Oracle: How to check if value exists in a collection type column?

Tags: oracle, sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

Let say I've two tables,

Table A

```
PK       SIZE  
89733     5 
83644     3  
87351     8
84423     11
```

Table B

```
 ID      Table_A_PK  
  1     89733,83644,86455   
  2     87351,89542  
  3     84132
  4     84566,84646
```

Note: **Column Table_A_PK** is of collection type, that's why it has many values.

I want to select value of **size** column of **Table A** if column **PK** value exits in **Table B's** column **Table_A_PK**

For this I tried this but it's not working and throwing an error

```
Select {a.SIZE} 
from {A as a} where {a.PK}  
in ({{ SELECT {b.Table_A_PK} FROM {B as b}
```

**Actual Result:** ORA-01722: invalid number

**Expected Result**

```
        SIZE  
         5  
         3  
         8
```

Comment: Storing comma separated values in a column is a **really**, really bad idea to begin with.

Comment: Sometimes you have no other option. When working with hybris, you have to work with a lot of legacy stuff you cannot change.

Comment: When you say `table_a_pk` is of collection type, do you actually mean that, in the technical sense? "Collection" is a technical term, and it definitely does **not** mean a comma-separated string of values. And columns of data type `collection` are indeed valid and are better than comma-separated strings.

Comment: @JohannesNolte - you always do have other options. If you (or your bosses) decide not to adopt those other options, that's OK, but that's by choice. For example: given a legacy table with comma-separated strings, one can create a proper relational table in first normal form by splitting the strings; rename the old table (for archival purposes) and create a **view** with the old table's name and holding code to recreate the comma-separated strings from the normalized data, so that legacy code doesn't break. All **new** code uses normalized data. Trivial solution, rarely adopted.

Comment: Show us the definition of your table or  the ddl used to create it.

Comment: @mathguy a collectiontype in hybris is a datatype that stores a collection as comma-separated-values into a column. It is a (deprecated) option of hybris' own ORM and hybris uses it in his own code to declare complex types that are used throughout the system. You could create a view, of course. However you need a query for that which is part of this question.

Comment: Though in case someone uses collectiontypes by choice, I am going to add a hint to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, collectiontypes are deprecated. If you use them by choice, prefer relations. They are much easier to work with.

I realized this once with the LIKE operator:

```
... WHERE Table_A_PK LIKE '%MYPK%'
```

However this is NOT best practice.

You might be able to use the Concat-Funktion to concatenate the % signs with the PK in the original table for a join. However I have not tried this.

```
SELECT {a.SIZE} 
FROM {A AS a JOIN B AS b 
ON {b.TABLE_A_PK} LIKE Concat('%', {a.pk}, '%') }
```

Comment: No luck: `ORA-00909: invalid number of arguments `

Comment: Maybe like this: Concat(Concat('%', {a.pk}), '%')

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `Relation` instead of `CollectionType`. If you are in the situation where you can't modify the itemType then you can search using **LIKE** operator

```
SELECT {a.SIZE}
FROM
{
   B AS b JOIN A AS a
   ON {b.TABLE_A_PK} LIKE CONCAT( '%', CONCAT( {a.PK} , '%' ) )
}
```

Comment: Isn't `ON {b.TABLE_A_PK} LIKE CONCAT( '%', CONCAT( {a.PK} , '%' ) )` ambiguous?
Ideally, primary keys must be compared with other primary keys to create a join.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is the way here. Because for collection type there is no reference between elements. The collection attribute is stored as a list of PK. Refer the same example [here](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/release5/FlexibleSearch+Tips+and+Tricks)